# d3 line chart coloured by a factor

Tags: date, d3.js, svg, path, linechart

I'm trying to make a line chart following upon Mike's work: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955

I feel like it's almost done but somehow lines don't show up on the web. When I check in console, I can see that path elements are bound to data as below:

```
<path class="line" d="M-697.1963619399295,450L-697.1963619388773,387.66856476995656L-697.1963619378253,385.2700720945643L-697.1963619367732,376.45940344046255L-697.1963619357211,365.5485611415587L-697.1963619346691,346.6313106168691L-697.196361933617,350.17558198677034L-697.196361932565,353.97503410091366L-697.1963619315128,312.6842695034037L-697.1963619304607,333.41027805240884L-697.1963619294087,321.8454859832573L-697.1963619283566,313.68973194787645L-697.1963619273046,241.5425737071716L-697.1963619262525,271.3271413254863L-697.1963619252003,280.314055452611L-697.1963619241483,209.81192123034214L-697.1963619230962,188.0957428765567L-697.1963619220442,185.33122960890398L-697.1963619209921,199.63550312298872L-697.19636191994,185.1121106885575L-697.196361918888,202.42299063181736L-697.1963619178358,217.14290559452036L-697.1963619167838,166.32145720825093L-697.1963619157317,137.91369117474824L-697.1963619146796,115.01923656419535L-697.1963619136276,117.12273665970253" style="stroke: rgb(31, 119, 180);"></path>
```

I assume the path doens't show up as the x position looks too low? The date is parsed and shown in the console like this:

```
Tue Jan 01 1991 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

But I only need Year information. I just assume some confusion may occur when the data is loaded but unsure.

My data looks like this:

```
time,EURO,OECD,USA,UK,
1991, 100,90,20,20,
1992, 20,40,50,30,
...
```

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<head> 
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y");

var xScale = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]); 
var zScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var line = d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
            .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.value); }); 

d3.csv("data.csv", type, function(data) {

    var countries = data.columns.slice(1).map(function(id) {
        return {
            id: id,
            values: data.map(function(d) { 
                return {date: d.time, 
                        value: d[id]};
                    })
        };
    });

    xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

    yScale.domain([
        d3.min(countries, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(d) { return d.value; }); }),
        d3.max(countries, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(d) { return d.value; }); })
        ]); 

    zScale.domain(countries.map(function(c) { return c.id; })); 

    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "Xaxis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")") 
        .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "Yaxis")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));


    var country = g.selectAll(".country")
                    .data(countries)
                    .enter().append('g')
                    .attr("class", "country");

    country.append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
            .style("stroke", function(d) { return zScale(d.id); }); 

});

function type(d, _, columns) {

    d.date = parseTime(d.time);

    for (var i = 1, n = columns.length, c; 
        i < n; ++i)
        d[c = columns[i]] = +d[c];


    return d; 
}

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you see anything if you set the stroke-width?

Comment: Hi @Andrew, thank you for your reply. I tried with stroke-width based on your advice, but lines didn't show up still. Would you mind give some other advices too? Thanks,

Comment: Hi Sue, could you create a plunk / blockbuilder with some sample data so that we can take a closer look?

Comment: In Mike's example, the style for the class `.line` has a `stroke-width: 1.5px;` This is declared as a css style in the head. You may need to add this as a style and not as d3 `.attr`.

Comment: With x-values near -700, the lines are being drawn off the screen. Looks like you are setting your xScale.domain to the integers from 1991 to the last year. But when you draw the lines, you are using that scale to map `d.date` which is in millis since 1970?

Comment: Thanks @SteveR, could you recommend a way to regulate the date to show since 1991?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSV has a column named `time`, not `date`.

Therefore, you have to change your row function...

```
d.time = parseTime(d.time);
```

... and the scale's domain:

```
xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { 
    return d.time; 
}));
```

Here is a demo with those changes, using just a couple of rows of data, for you to see it working: https://plnkr.co/edit/phQr3Ekd6ztZAGt9SE4v?p=preview

Comment: Hi @Gerado, thank you for your reply. It worked to render the lines! Thanks,